# Invoking "make" failed

Tags: catkin-make, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 & ROS Hydro. While going through this tutorial [here](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29) i encountered the following error upon typing:

`catkin_make`

```
asaad@VAIO:~/catkin_ws$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/asaad/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/asaad/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/asaad/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/asaad/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/asaad/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/asaad/catkin_ws/build"
####
####
#### Running command: "make -j4 -l4" in "/home/asaad/catkin_ws/build"
####
[  0%] [  8%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 16%] [ 16%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
Building CXX object begginer_tutorials/CMakeFiles/add_two_ints_server.dir/src/add_two_ints_server.cpp.o
Building CXX object begginer_tutorials/CMakeFiles/add_two_ints_client.dir/src/add_two_ints_client.cpp.o
[ 16%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[ 25%] Built target listener
[ 33%] Built target talker
[ 50%] Built target begginer_tutorials_generate_messages_cpp
[ 83%] Built target begginer_tutorials_generate_messages_py
[100%] Built target begginer_tutorials_generate_messages_lisp
[100%] Built target begginer_tutorials_generate_messages
/home/asaad/catkin_ws/src/begginer_tutorials/src/add_two_ints_server.cpp:2:43: fatal error: beginner_tutorials/AddTwoInts.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
/home/asaad/catkin_ws/src/begginer_tutorials/src/add_two_ints_client.cpp:2:43: fatal error: beginner_tutorials/AddTwoInts.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [begginer_tutorials/CMakeFiles/add_two_ints_server.dir/src/add_two_ints_server.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [begginer_tutorials/CMakeFiles/add_two_ints_server.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[2]: *** [begginer_tutorials/CMakeFiles/add_two_ints_client.dir/src/add_two_ints_client.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [begginer_tutorials/CMakeFiles/add_two_ints_client.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make" failed
```

I saw the other answers related to this but couldn't find the error myself.
EDITED:

The CMakeLists.txt file contains the following data:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(begginer_tutorials)

## Find catkin macros and libraries
## if COMPONENTS list like find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS xyz)
## is used, also find other catkin packages
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs
  message_generation
)

## System dependencies are found with CMake's conventions
# find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system)


## Uncomment this if the package has a setup.py. This macro ensures
## modules and global scripts declared therein get installed
## See http://ros.org/doc/api/catkin/html/user_guide/setup_dot_py.html
# catkin_python_setup()

################################################
## Declare ROS messages, services and actions ##
################################################

## To declare and build messages, services or actions from within this
## package, follow these steps:
## * Let MSG_DEP_SET be the set of packages whose message types you use in
##   your messages/services/actions (e.g. std_msgs, actionlib_msgs, ...).
## * In the file package.xml:
##   * add a build_depend and a run_depend tag for each package in MSG_DEP_SET
##   * If MSG_DEP_SET isn't empty the following dependencies might have been
##     pulled in transitively but can be declared for certainty nonetheless:
##     * add a build_depend tag for "message_generation"
##     * add a run_depend tag for "message_runtime"
## * In this file (CMakeLists.txt):
##   * add "message_generation" and every package in MSG_DEP_SET to
##     find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS ...)
##   * add "message_runtime" and every package in MSG_DEP_SET to
##     catkin_package(CATKIN_DEPENDS ...)
##   * uncomment the add_*_files sections below as needed
##     and list every .msg/.srv/.action file to be processed
##   * uncomment the generate_messages entry below
##   * add every package in MSG_DEP_SET to generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES ...)

## Generate messages in the 'msg' folder
 add_message_files(
   FILES
   Num.msg
  
 )

## Generate services in the 'srv' folder
 add_service_files(
    FILES
    AddTwoInts.srv
 )

## Generate actions in the 'action' folder
# add_action_files(
#   FILES
#   Action1.action
#   Action2.action
# )

## Generate added messages and services with any dependencies listed here
 generate_messages(
   DEPENDENCIES
   std_msgs
 )

###################################
## catkin specific configuration ##
###################################
## The catkin_package macro generates cmake config files for your package
## Declare things to be passed to dependent projects
## INCLUDE_DIRS: uncomment this if you package contains header files
## LIBRARIES: libraries you create in this project that dependent projects also need
## CATKIN_DEPENDS: catkin_packages dependent projects also need
## DEPENDS: system dependencies of this project that dependent projects also need
catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES begginer_tutorials
  CATKIN_DEPENDS message_runtime roscpp rospy std_msgs
  DEPENDS system_lib
)

###########
## Build ##
###########

## Specify additional locations of header files
## Your package locations should be listed before other locations
# include_directories(include)
include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

## Declare a cpp library
# add_library(begginer_tutorials
#   src/${PROJECT_NAME}/begginer_tutorials.cpp
# )

## Declare a cpp executable
# add_executable(begginer_tutorials_node src/begginer_tutorials_node.cpp)

## Add cmake target dependencies of the executable/library
## as an example, message headers may need to be generated before nodes
# add_dependencies(begginer_tutorials_node begginer_tutorials_generate_messages_cpp)

## Specify libraries to link a library or executable target against
# target_link_libraries(begginer_tutorials_node
#   ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
# )

#############
## Install ##
#############

# all install targets should use catkin DESTINATION variables
# See http://ros.org/doc/api/catkin/html/adv_user_guide/variables.html

## Mark executable scripts (Python etc.) for installation
## in contrast to setup.py, you can choose the destination
# install(PROGRAMS
#   scripts/my_python_script
#   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
# )

## Mark executables and/or libraries for installation
# install(TARGETS begginer_tutorials begginer_tutorials_node
#   ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
#   LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
#   RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
# )

## Mark cpp header files for installation
# install(DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}/
#   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
#   FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h"
#   PATTERN ".svn" EXCLUDE
# )

## Mark other files for installation (e.g. launch and bag files, etc.)
# install(FILES
#   # myfile1
#   # myfile2
#   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}
# )

#############
## Testing ##
#############

## Add gtest based cpp test target and link libraries
# catkin_add_gtest(${PROJECT_NAME}-test test/test_begginer_tutorials.cpp)
# if(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME}-test)
#   target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}-test ${PROJECT_NAME})
# endif()

## Add folders to be run by python nosetests
# catkin_add_nosetests(test)


include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(talker src/talker.cpp)
target_link_libraries(talker ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(talker beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_cpp)

add_executable(listener src/listener.cpp)
target_link_libraries(listener ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(listener beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_cpp)

add_executable(add_two_ints_server src/add_two_ints_server.cpp)
target_link_libraries(add_two_ints_server ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(add_two_ints_server beginner_tutorials_gencpp)

add_executable(add_two_ints_client src/add_two_ints_client.cpp)
target_link_libraries(add_two_ints_client ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(add_two_ints_client beginner_tutorials_gencpp)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215426/invoking-%22make%22-failed/) by [Asaad Irfan](https://answers.ros.org/users/23193/asaad-irfan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2015-08-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well, the node you try to compile (I guess from [this Tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient%28c%2B%2B%29), not the one you linked) doesn't find the header `AddTwoInts.h` for including.

Have you (strictly) followed [this part of the tutorial for creating msg and srv](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv#Using_srv)? Is the `AddTwoInts.srv` in your `beginner_tutorials` package?

If this doesn't help you, please post the contents of your `CMakeLists.txt` (by editing your post above).

---

**EDIT**

Alright, the problem seems to be that you actually called the package/directory/project `begginer_tutorials`.
The error says it cannot in include `beginner_tutorials/AddTwoInts.h`. Note the different spelling of `begginer`/`beginner`.

When you create msgs/srvs, the generated headers are placed in a subfolder with the name of the project.
So please change the include to `begginer_tutorials/AddTwoInts.h`. This should resolve the issue. (Or, alternatively, rename the package as well as all occurences of `begginer` with `beginner`).

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2015-08-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Asaad Irfan](https://answers.ros.org/users/23193/asaad-irfan/) on 2015-08-09**:
Yes ,there is a file named AddTwoInts.srv in begginer_tutorials in the begginer_tutorials package at this location:

```
catkin_ws/src/begginer_tutorials/srv
```

Yes i followed [this part of the tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv#Using_srv)  completely.

**Comment by [Asaad Irfan](https://answers.ros.org/users/23193/asaad-irfan/) on 2015-08-10**:
Thank you mig. The spelling error(begginer & beginner) starts from [this](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv) tutorial & continues [here](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29) as well. if anyone copies & pastes the text, ERROR!

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2015-08-10**:
So this is solved? (If yes, please accept the answer by clicking on the check mark)

But the correct spelling is `beginner` and this is consistent throughout the tutorials you linked.
Maybe you had a typo in the `catkin_create_pkg` command when creating the pkg? If not, where is the error exactly?

**Comment by [Asaad Irfan](https://answers.ros.org/users/23193/asaad-irfan/) on 2015-08-10**:
My bad. I was typing 'begginer' in all the previous tutorials and just started copying & pasting from these tutorials so thats why.